# Knex and node.js how do i dive into the return object

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

I have a node.js API that im using MySQL with Knex, how do i go about targeting a specific value in the return.

```
db.raw('SELECT * FROM _sessions WHERE sessionkey = ?', [apiKey]).then(function(resp) {

    if (resp[0].length) {
      exports.securitycheck=true;
      console.log(resp[0].userid);
    } else {
      exports.securitycheck=false;
    }

});
```

However `resp[0].userid` returns undefined

heres the log of the resp data :

```
[ RowDataPacket {
sessionid: 1,
sessionkey: '123abc',
userid: 1,
accountid: 1,
sessionstart: 2017-08-24T01:01:09.000Z,
sessionlast: 2017-08-24T01:01:09.000Z,
alloweddurationseconds: 1800 } ]
```

the end goal here is that if the query returns data, take the userid and accountid and assign them to variables

Comment: Is `resp[0].length` defined ?

Comment: Probably you meant `resp.length`

Comment: yeah resp[0].length is defined

Comment: @Malice even if i remove the [0] length is still defined, and the log is still outputting undefined

Comment: Where did you get the log of the resp data ?

Comment: @Malice before the if statement inside .then(), i used console.log(resp[0])

Comment: That is wierd, can you make sure log is coming from `console.log(resp[0].userid);`, probably concatenate a string with it and see

Comment: resp cannot disappear like that, try printing `resp[0]` and `resp[0]['userid']` as werll

Answer (score 0):

Corrected by using

```
resp[0][0].userid
```